# Reproducing a script in a widget (Magento ecommerce)

Tags: magento, widget

So there's this customized widget at this Magento store:

```
{{widget type="cmswidgets/category" title="Novos Produtos" featured_category="category/140" products_amount="15" column_count="5" template="signativa/cmswidgets/category.phtml" cache_lifetime="3600"}}
```

This widget/script has 2 variables in it from the Magento store, which are:

1. Credit card parcels (12x)
2. The discount when paying with cash (12%)

This widget is called "Novos Produtos" (New products in English) and it looks like this:
https://www.rbaimportados.com/teste-produtos-2

And it's code looks like this (just of one product as example):

```html
<div class="product-info" style="min-height: 248px;">
    <a class="product-name" href="https://www.rbaimportados.com/doogee-s95-pro.html"
       title="Smartphone Doogee S95 Pro - 6.3&quot; FHD+ And. 9.0 Helio P90 Octa 2.2GHz 8/128GB 48+8+8/16MP IP68">Smartphone
        Doogee S95 Pro - 6.3" FHD+ And. 9.0 Helio P90 Octa 2.2GHz 8/128GB 48+8+8/16MP IP68</a>

    <div class="price-box">

        <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label">De:</span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-1046">
                    R$2.500,00                </span>
        </p>

        <p class="special-price">
            <span class="price-label">Preço Promocional</span>
            <span class="price" id="product-price-1046">
                    R$2.299,90                </span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <span id="container-nr-pcl-1046" class="nr-pcl"><span id="nr-pcl-1046">12x</span> de <span id="valor-pcl-1046"
                                                                                               class="big">R$191,66</span></span>
    <p class="desconto-boleto">ou R$2.023,91 à vista</p>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="button" title="Comprar" class="button btn-cart"
                onclick="setLocation('https://www.rbaimportados.com/doogee-s95-pro.html')">
            <span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
        <ul class="add-to-links">
            <li><a href="https://www.rbaimportados.com/wishlist/index/add/product/1046/form_key/2ri9tViQD6d8V1AO/"
                   class="link-wishlist">Adicionar aos Favoritos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In comparison, here can be seen the default Magento "New products" widget, that has no Credit card parcels and/or Cash discount scripts:
https://www.rbaimportados.com/teste-produtos

**Therefore, please, how can I add those scripts

```
        <span id="container-nr-pcl-1046" class="nr-pcl"><span id="nr-pcl-1046">12x</span> de <span id="valor-pcl-1046"
                                                                                               class="big">R$191,66</span></span>
        <p class="desconto-boleto">ou R$2.023,91 à vista</p>
```

so they can work with the default "New products" default widget from Magento?**

I was wondering also if can be done in CSS or if has to be in Javascript...

Thanks in advance!